# How can I convert DataSet a to a DataReader?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, datareader

How can I convert a DataSet to a DataReader?

Comment: You can't. If you want more explanation, please provide more information.

Comment: I feel there is a flaw in what you are trying to do. What ARE you trying to do at a higher level?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following code to change dataset to `DataReader`:

```
DataTableReader rd = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
```

Answer (score 5):

Both DataSet and DataTable expose a method CreateDataReader which
creates a DataTableReader. 
Check these links -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.createdatareader.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.createdatareader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`DataSet` has a method called `CreateDataReader` which will create a `DataTableReader`, but I don't think that you can create a `DataReader`.

[DataSet.CreateDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.DATA.DATASET.CREATEDATAREADER);k(SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true)

Answer (score 0):

DataSet is a disconnected in-memory object. DataReader is a connected unidirectional object.

So I guess it is not possible.

Is it really needed?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx - Reads a forward-only stream of rows from a data source. Says nothing about being 'Connected' to a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate thru DataSet, you don't need a DataReader. DataSet is a disconnected in-memory object so iterate thru it using for-each:

```
foreach(var row in ds.Tables["YourTable"])
{
     var value = row.Field<int>("ID"); // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a DataSet to a DbDataReader.

You can however create a DbDataReader that will read results from the DataSet by calling the CreateDataReader method on the DataSet.

However, this seems like a strange thing to want to do. You can simply iterate through the results contained in the DataSet using the Tables property of DataSet and The Rows property of DataTable. Using a DbDataReader would restrict you to forward only access to the results. The only benefit I can see from using a DbDataReader would be if you had an API call to make which required one as a parameter.

If your DataSet is the result of a SELECT command from a database, you should be able to get a DbDataReader by calling DbCommand.ExecuteReader(). This will cut out the DataSet altogether and result in something that is more efficient.